# Востребованность Unix-программистов

Tags: unix, работа

Кто-нибудь из уважаемой публики может сказать, насколько сегодня на рынке востребованы специалисты по Linux/Unix программированию?

Comment: А чем по вашему отличается Unix программист от не Unix программиста?

Comment: Основательным знанием системных вызовов Unix, программированием терминала, знанием специфических юниксовых библиотек, навык создания GUI в GTK+, Qt, умением использовать юниксовые средства разработки: gcc, g++, make, умением создавать дистрибутивы для юниксовых систем, в частности для Линукса - rpm, deb и т.д, и т.п. Этого мало?

Comment: Я попрошу не путать gcc, g++, make как и Qt не являются чисто юниксовыми вещами. Qt это изначально кроссплатформенная библиотека, остальные три есть и под windows, причем их тоже довольно таки часто используют. Если говорить о чисто юниксовых вещах как пакеты и специфических для unix библиотек, то их знание никогда не будет лишним. Я бы сейчас делал упор на Windows (т.к. она на подавляющем большинстве пользовательских машин) в свободное время изучая Unix.

Comment: Все это мне известно. Но вопрос вообще о другом: много ли сейчас на рынке предложений работы по написанию софта для юниксов.

Comment: Вы хотите узнать конкретные примеры где этим занимаются? WMWare, Ideco, Endian, Yandex, Google. Я думаю список нет смысла продолжать. Если вы хотите этим заниматься - вы найдете место для этого.

Comment: Кстати, много известно распространенных программ для Windows, написанных с использованием, например, Qt? Я знаю только Vlc и Google Earth. С помощью GTK - GIMP, да и то, это изначально линуксовая программа, портированная на Windows.

Comment: Насколько я помню еще Opera и Psi

Comment: Однако, не густо. И опять же - кросс-платформенные приложения. Видно, чисто под виндовс на них не пишут. Все же Qt и GTK+ - юниксовые вещи.

Comment: Посмотрите на продукты тех фирм что я перечислил думаю даже если их мало по количеству то по бюджету некоторые не из дешевых

Comment: Skype на Qt

Comment: qBittorrent, который по фичам уже делает uTorrent

Comment: могу добавить что программирование под *nix приводит мозги в порядок, в плане следования рекомендациям и выделения чего важно, а что нет. Вообще говоря навыки они обычно платформонезависимые, если только вы не системным программированием занимаетесь.

Answer (score 7):

Востребованы, зарплата не хуже, чем у windows программистов.

Comment: А какие основные востребованные направления программирования для юниксов?

Comment: Я чаще всего сталкивался с позициями, связанными с Embedded Linux

Comment: При разработке серверов с высокой нагрузкой по моим наблюдениям юникс оч. приветствуется (в описаниях подобных вакансий стабильно встречал в желательных требованиях)

Comment: Я бы сказал, зарплата лучше, чем у Windows-программистов, но и требования к квалификации существенно выше.

Answer (score 7):

Unix программисты , в основном восстребованы,я бы сказал в сфере Телекоммуникаций,IP TV,и конечно же , серверных технологиях. Очень высокие ЗП.

Comment: Поддерживаю, буквально недавно общался с хедхантерами МТС. Они нуждаются в очень квалифицированных Unix-программистах.

Answer (score 4):

если будете глубоко шарить в теме, то будете востребованы как специалист, вне зависимости от общих тенденций рынка

Answer (score 3):

[Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=ru&sa=X&ei=DVSUTdipMofHswbC4ODCCA&ved=0CCkQBSgA&q=%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+Unix+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82&spell=1) - 10+ страниц

[Head Hunter](http://hh.ru/applicant/searchvacancyresult.xml?text=unix+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82&professionalAreaId=0&desireableCompensation=&compensationCurrencyCode=RUR) 470 вакансий

[Habrahabr](http://habrahabr.ru/job/?action=find&sector_id=0&keyword=Unix+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82&country=&region=&city=&pay=) 6 вакансий

Как видите вакансий не мало

Comment: У более чем половины вакансий в списке unix только приветствуется, реальное соотношение виндовс к линукс по хедхантеру 5:1

Comment: Не играет роли. Вакансии есть, если есть желание этим заниматься - то человек найдет место, если ему это не нужно то и не надо в это лезть.

Comment: Это уже другой разговор, но реалии таковы, что потребность в unix-разработчиках не так уж и высока, одних только программистов под .NET требуется в 2 раза больше.

Answer (score 1):

По моим наблюдениям юниксоиды в основном востребованы в крупных корпорациях. Малый и средний в большинстве "сидит" под Windows. Конечно, сфера юниксоидов это серверные технологии, хоть Windows и оттяпал кусок (приличный надо сказать) серверного рынка, но все же Unix там все еще заправляет бал.

Лет 20 назад - все было не так: Windows сидел на десктопах, на серверах был Unix, доживали свои дни IBM/360, VAX VMS и проч.

Я думаю еще 10-к лет Unix на серверах продержится. Хотя кто его знает, сейчас все так зыбко, текуче. Может через 10 лет и серверов то не останется :)

Answer (score 1):

Unix/Cи программисты востребован, основные направления серверные компоненты для WEB, телекоммуникации, voice-IP, embed системы.

Надо отлично знать все системные вызовы, для многих проектов нужно хорошо знать многопоточность, для WEB сектора - кроме HTTP и HTML, хорошо знать написание сетевых демонов, использование разных алгоритмов поиска, работа с БД
для телекоммуникационного сектора стек IP/SIP/SЕP/ICDN и прочие..
ориентироваться и иметь опыт работы с разными БД и NoSQL, знать минимум по алгоритмам всякие там сортикровки и поиск в деревьях.

в общем направлений хватает